# Python property being ignored, acting like an attribute

Tags: python, properties

I've got this RoomPlaceholder class with a distance property; when you set the distance property, it should automatically calculate what the x and y of the class should be, based on a random angle and the distance.

```
class RoomPlaceholder:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.id = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(8))
        self.angle = Util.getRandomAngle() # = random.random() * math.pi * 2
        self.distance = 0

    @property
    def distance(self):
        print "gamma"
        return self._distance
    @distance.setter
    def distance(self, value):
        print "delta"
        self._distance = value
        coords = Util.getXYByDist(value, self.angle) # translates angle and distance into integer (x, y)
        print coords
        self._x = coords[0]
        self._y = coords[1]

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s: [%sx%s] @ (%s, %s) Distance: %s. Angle: %s." % (self.id, self.width, self.height, self.x, self.y, self.distance, self.angle)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    room = RoomPlaceholder(5,5)
    print "%s\n" % room.distance
    room.distance = 10
    print "%s\n" % room.distance
    print room
    pass
```

However, it's not working. Based on the output from the console, it looks like it's treating distance as an attribute rather than a property; note that I've got print statements in both the getter ("gamma") and setter ("delta") methods, but we never see either in the output when I get or set the distance:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):0

  File "D:\Dropbox\Programming\Python\DungeonGenerator\NewDungeonGenerator.py", line 142, in <module>

10

    print room
  File "D:\Dropbox\Programming\Python\DungeonGenerator\NewDungeonGenerator.py", line 132, in __repr__
    return "%s: [%sx%s] @ (%s, %s) Distance: %s. Angle: %s." % (self.id, self.width, self.height, self.x, self.y, self.distance, self.angle)
  File "D:\Dropbox\Programming\Python\DungeonGenerator\NewDungeonGenerator.py", line 97, in x
    return self._x
AttributeError: RoomPlaceholder instance has no attribute '_x'
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

I'm using Python 2.7, and this is being run via Sublime Text 3 in Windows 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`property`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#property) only works for [new-style classes](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle).  You need to make `RoomPlaceholder` a subclass of `object` by declaring it thusly:

```
class RoomPlaceholder(object):
    # etc.
```

Comment: I've used properties elsewhere without difficulty, and without using that style of definition. For example, see https://github.com/Asmor/python-roguelike/blob/master/Level.py#L43 Why would it be working there but not here? EDIT: To clarify, your solution does work; I'm just confused why I haven't run into this problem previously

Comment: @Asmor: Were you previously working solely in Python 3?  In Py3, all classes are new-style, and the `(object)` bit is redundant, while in Python 2, `(object)` is needed to get `property` *et alii* to work.

Comment: I did actually start this project in py3, but I've switched to py2. Upon further inspection, that line I mentioned isn't actually working correctly, but its failure wasn't as noticeable. Thanks again!